# Slim 2 redirect is not working

Tags: php, redirect, slim, slim-2

Redirect is not working in slim 2 & it returns below error for this line

```
$application->redirect($application->urlFor('details', array(
    'slug' => $slug,
)));
```

Is there any settings in **.conf** file ?. Please help me to fix this.  Thanks in advance.

**Error**

```
    Slim_Exception_Stop Object
(
    [message:protected] => 
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /usr/local/test/enduser/vendors/Slim/Slim.php
    [line:protected] => 810
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal one-file test case that shows the problem.

Comment: I'm testing my code in interworx panel where only redirect is not working ($application->render is working fine) & same code tested in the other panels (also in local) redirect is working fine. I have tried with simple redirect examples still its throwing above error. Is there any settings in .conf file ? OR in php.ini file ?